# Power BI Bar & two line chart start defaulting To Target start line

Tags: powerbi, report, dax

I have a chart that  I want to display in Power BI and display the two line  side by side
The target is 25%. When I display it I have the below chart

[image]

My expect output should be. So that the secondary axis starts from 0(zero) %
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this in the formatting pane for your Y-axis:

[image]